# how to get files from particular folder in windows 8 using windows store app programming?

Tags: c#, windows-8, windows-store-apps

how to access this path " AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent " and get files from this path " AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent " in windows 8 using windows store programming in C#

Answer (score 0):

You can't access this location from a Windows Store app. These apps are running in a sandboxed environment and there's only a limited set of locations they can access. By default these are:

- app install directory (inside `c:\Program Files\WindowsApps\`, your app's subfolder only)
- app date locations (inside `c:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\`, your app's subfolder only)
- user's Downloads folder (only to files and folder's that your app created)

By requesting additional capabilities, you can access as well:

- user's Documents library
- user's Music library
- user's Pictures library
- user's Videos library
- removable devices

By using [`FileOpenPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.fileopenpicker.aspx) or [`FolderPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) you can also access any files or folders the user selects.

Comment: Actually i want to show recently used files list in windows 8, Recently used files are stores in this path "AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Recent " ,thats'y i trying to access this folder.Is there any possible by using " Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder" namespace.

Comment: No, `Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingFolder` points to `c:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Packages\AppFolder\RoamingState\`. As I've already mentioned above, due to sandboxed environment your app doesn't have access to this folder. You could potentially get the user to select the folder once and store its reference to [FutureAccessList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx). Still the folder contains only links and this won't grant you access to files the links point to.